# extracting a large Postgres table and writing it to a csv file using Python Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, csv

I'm reading postgres table, extracting data and loading it into a csv file. The issue I have is that I'm able to read up to 5gb TABLE and successfully create a csv file. One of my tables is 35 GB and am unable to create a csv file, and the process is getting killed.

I suspect my dataframe is not able to handle large size.

What can we do to overcome this and create csv files successfully?

```
def table_to_csv(sql, file_path, dbname,port, user):

    """This function creates a csv file from PostgreSQL with query
    """
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname=dbname,  port=port, user=user)
        print("Connecting to Database")
        # Get data into pandas dataframe
        df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
        # Write to csv file
        df.to_csv(file_path, encoding='utf-8', header = True,doublequote = True, sep=',', index=False)
        print("CSV File has been created")
        conn.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: {}".format(str(e)))
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Try doing it chunk by chunk. Anyway using pandas to work with 35 gb data is not a good practice.

Comment: Is your database running on the same machine as your Python code?

Comment: yes my database and Python code are running in the same EC2 (aws)machine. I have to read 20 tables from my db and create csv files, only 2 of the tables are more than 30 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your database is running on the local machine your most efficient option will probably be to use [PostgreSQL's `COPY` command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html), e.g. something like

```
COPY table_name TO file_path WITH (FORMAT csv, ENCODING UTF8, HEADER);
```

PostgreSQL will save the data directly to the file itself, without having to read it all into memory at once or have your Python code touch it at all.

You should be able to run this via `psycopg2`'s standard [`cursor.execute` function](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute). Of course, you could also run it via `psql` or another PostgreSQL client of your choice.

Comment: Should i have the copy command as part of the cursor.execute function?

Comment: @Ron, I haven't run it this way but I think something like `cur.execute("COPY table_name TO file_path WITH (FORMAT csv, ENCODING UTF8, HEADER)")` should do the trick. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yep let me try it this way :) Hopefully this will work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked with Cursor and its copy expert function. Here is the code snippet

```
  cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    #execute
    with open("/sample.csv", 'w') as fd:

        cur.copy_expert("COPY sample TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV,  HEADER TRUE, 
        FORCE_QUOTE *)", fd)
```